# nonblocking waitpid() in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to do non-blocking waitpid, according to [perl man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html), `waitpid($pid,  WNOHANG);` will do. But the following seems to be blocking. The result of the printf will take 2 seconds to show up.

```
$pid = fork;
if (!$pid) {
    exec("sleep 2");
}
waitpid($pid,  WNOHANG);
$retCode = $?;
printf "%04x\n", $retCode;
```

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mistake number 1: you didn't enable warnings.

Mistake number 2: you didn't declare WNOHANG. So it's a bareword, which becomes the string `'WNOHANG'`. The string then becomes 0 with no warning when interpreted as a number, because it doesn't look like a number. So you called `waitpid` with flags=0, instead of the WNOHANG flag you intended.

```
use warnings;
use POSIX 'WNOHANG';
```

Comment: Thanks @wumpus-q-wumbley